# How to create URL Link outside UI Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC 3 application project, that references a `ServiceProject` which executes commands like `CreateNewPost(Foo entity)`...

IMPORTANT: This ServiceProject cant reference `System.Web.MVC`

I need to create an email(this method is on my ServiceProject), that contains a url link to some specific page (example `TestController/FooAction`) on my system, but I want to create a relative URL, that will generate correctly on production environment, test environment, or even develop environment(localhost).

How do I create that URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious way is to pass a base url to the methods (or maybe to the entire project by dependency injection).

---

Another way, if you can  reference `System.Web` and there is a HTTP request involved, you can use

```
HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +  HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath
```

`Scheme` gives you the url scheme (a.k.a. *protocol*).

`Authority` gives you the hostname and port for the request server.

`ApplicationPath` gives you the virtual root path of the ASP.NET application on the server.

---

Looks like you can't do it without a `HttpRequest`, as previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164261/get-host-name-without-using-httprequest).

Answer (score 2):

This does require reference to `System.Web.MVC`, but it should give you a basic idea how it can be done.
I created an extension to help me with this:

```
    public static string GetAbsoluteURL(this RouteCollection routes, RequestContext context, RouteValueDictionary values, HttpProtocolType httpProtocol)
    {
        string host;

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
        {
            host = context.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority;
        }
        else
        {
            host = context.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host;
        }

        string virtualPath = routes.GetVirtualPath(context, "Default", values).VirtualPath;

        string protocol = httpProtocol == HttpProtocolType.HTTP ? "http" : "https";

        return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", protocol, host, virtualPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reference `System.Web.MVC`, you can't use `UrlHelper`.

However, you can use the `System.Uri` class which is in `System.dll`

So you could calculate the base uri in your web project, pass it as a string to your service project and then use `Uri` to create the final uri:

```
// controller in web project
ServiceProject.SendEmail( Url.Content( "~" ), ... );

// service project
public void SendEmail( string baseUriAsString, ... )
{
  var baseUri = new Uri( baseUriAsString, UriKind.Absolute );
  string relativeUri = ...
  var finalUri = new Uri( baseUri, relativeUri );
  ...
```

See MSDN: [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

Comment: passing the URL prefix as a parameter doesn't make any sense on my real world situation. This will become a bad smell on my code.